# :nth-child fails to honour CSS attributes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I coded a breadcrumbs/page navigation feature for a website I'm developing. I have a breadcrumb code where I want my CSS to place a bottom border on the `li` when the user hovers over each item - which it does perfectly (a shocker that it's actually done something I told it to), however, naturally & understandably it also places a border under the arrows. Therefore, we need an `nth-child` to tell it NOT to place a `border-bottom:solid` CSS attribute under every `li` which contains an arrow.

As you can also see, there is a `border-bottom: solid` under the `:nth-child(last)` as this is the active page.

Is there a particular reason as to why. despite me employing the statement "every other `li` item from the second `li` item - which is an arrow `li`, in the form if `2n+2` does Dreamweaver still fail to **NOT** place a `border-bottom-style:none`?

Please see my code below:

```css
.page-nav-breadcrumbs a{
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #550AF1;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(odd){
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(odd):hover{
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(1){
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:last-child{
    border-bottom: solid 2px #550AF1!important;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2n+2){ <!------This is the culprit----->
    border-bottom-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
} 

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:first-child{
    border-bottom-style: none!important;
    padding-left: 0px!important;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:hover{
    border-bottom: solid 2px #550AF1;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="page-nav-breadcrumbs">
            <li><strong>You are here:</strong></li>
            <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li>&raquo;</li>
            <li><a href="/index.html">Corporate</a></li>
            <li>&raquo;</li>
            <li><a href="/index.html">Financials</a></li>
            <li>&raquo;</li>
            <li><a href="/index.html">Statement of Comprehensive Income</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe instead of `.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2n+2)` you should write

```css
.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2n+1):hover{
  border-bottom-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h4ktaq0g/2/

Also maybe it would be better to assign special class for arrows, this can work faster than iterating over li's to find for which to apply style.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `:hover` and you need `2n+3`, since the arrows start with the 3rd `li`.

So the full selector should be `.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2n+3):hover`

```css
.page-nav-breadcrumbs a {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #550AF1;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(odd) {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(odd):hover {
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:last-child {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #550AF1!important;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2n+3):hover {
  border-bottom-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:first-child {
  border-bottom-style: none!important;
  padding-left: 0px!important;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #550AF1;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="page-nav-breadcrumbs">
  <li><strong>You are here:</strong></li>
  <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li>&raquo;</li>
  <li><a href="/index.html">Corporate</a></li>
  <li>&raquo;</li>
  <li><a href="/index.html">Financials</a></li>
  <li>&raquo;</li>
  <li><a href="/index.html">Statement of Comprehensive Income</a></li>
</ul>
```

Note: You might want to add `padding-bottom: 7px;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to avoid the vertical movement of subsequent elements when you hover the links (see snippet above).

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach would be to either apply the underline styles to just `a` tags rather than all `li`, or remove the arrows from the HTML altogether and use `::after` to add them to the relevant breadcrumb links. The main addition here is:

```
.page-nav-breadcrumbs li::after {
  content: "»";
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:first-of-type::after,
.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:last-of-type::after {
  content: "";
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

which will add the right arrow after all `li` except the first and the last ones.

```css
.page-nav-breadcrumbs a {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #550AF1;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li::after {
  content: "»";
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:first-of-type::after,
.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:last-of-type::after {
  content: "";
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li:last-child {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #550AF1!important;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs a:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 2px #550AF1;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.page-nav-breadcrumbs li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="page-nav-breadcrumbs">
  <li><strong>You are here:</strong></li>
  <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/corporate.html">Corporate</a></li>
  <li><a href="/financials.html">Financials</a></li>
  <li><a href="/income.html">Statement of Comprehensive Income</a></li>
</ul>
```